# How can I target dynamic classNames?

Tags: css, discord

Hi i'm currently working on a custom css file for my discord and to change some of the elements looks i need to know how to define a class in which it has an id after a hyphen eg.

```
<div class="avatarDefault-ai3nf">
```

how would you select by `avatarDefault`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
[class^="avatarDefault"] {
  /* styles here */
}
```

It targets all elements with `class` attribute starting with "avatarDefault".

You can also use `[class*="avatarDefault"]` which targets all elements containing `avatarDefault` string in class.

Note: When dealing with `class`, it's better to use *contains* operator as in larger scale applications, where you add/remove classes using JavaScript, you can't be sure the string always remains at the start of the `class` attribute. For example, the *starts with* selector won't match this element:

```
<div class="random-class avatarDefault-ai3nf"></div>
```

... but the *contains* selector will match it.

---

However, if you can change your markup (or whatever it is that creates it), it would be best if you placed the unique identifier inside `id` attribute and use the `class` as collection identifier:

```
<div id="ai3nf" class="avatarDefault"></div>
```

... and use `.avatarDefault` to style the elements of your collection.